# web.config problem converting url to https

Tags: iis, https, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I've looked at many suggestions on this and other sites but haven't found anything that completely solves my problem. I have a site whose SSL certificate is only for [www.site.co.uk](http://www.site.co.uk), not site.co.uk. So I need something that will add a missing https:// and www. The rules I've tried are:

```
<rule name="Redirect not www">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.teams-unpuzzled\.co\.uk$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="not HTTPS or not www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="(HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="www." ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

and this works for most inputs but an input of https://teams-unpuzzled.co.uk doesn't get a www added and the browser flags it as not secure, and an input of [www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk/online-team-building](http://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk/online-team-building) loses the last part and comes out as https://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk

30/07 @Abraham I've tried Require Server Name Indication but it made things worse. I've now come up with these rules which seem to do the trick. (Doing it with boxoff.co.uk now as that's less critical.)

```
    <rule name="Not HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.boxoff.co.uk/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="HTTPS and not www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
            <add input="(HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^boxoff\.co\.uk$" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.boxoff.co.uk/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

We at least should ensure that `teams-unpuzzled.co.uk` points to the IP of our website so that it can apply the URL rules. Did you add a DNS entry to complete that?
Once you make sure that the other domain name(failed to match the `www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk`) points to the IP of our current website, these URL rules will take effect. Please refer to the below rules.

```
                <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRules" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
//we had to ensure that the other domain name points to the IP of our website so that the below condition will take effect.
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.teams-unpuzzled\.co\.uk$" negate="true" />
//Also, add an http binding to the website in order to match the below condition.
                        <add input="{https}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk{Request_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

At last, the missing fragment could be solved by using the `{Request_URI}` variable.

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk{Request_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Official documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#accessing-url-parts-from-a-rewrite-rule
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but I don't know much about DNS. If I do ipconfig /displaydns I get for www.teams-unpuzzled.co.uk: A (Host) Record: 10.254.113.30 and the same for teams-unpuzzled.co.uk. 
Anyhow, I applied your suggested rule and it's fixed the 'missing fragment' problem - thank you.
The only thing not right is `https://teams-unpuzzled.co.uk` - on Firefox it always comes up as 'not secure' On Edge and Chrome, it immediately comes up as 'not secure' then it continues to the https://www version and shows it as secure.

Comment: I mean that the other domain name is able to access the website correctly without URL Rewrite rules. It seems that the configuration is correct.
Besides, did you add another binding for the `teams-unpuzzled.co.uk` domain name with the proper certificate?
Please refer to the preceding post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656301/url-rewrite-invalid-certificate/62672435#62672435